# Как получить значение переменной вне цикла for?

Tags: golang

Мне нужно посчитать количество операций,приводящих `input` к единице. Возникает ошибка при попытке вернуть переменную `steps` вне цикла `for`. Подскажите,как это можно сделать?

```golang
func CollatzConjecture(input int) (int,error){
if input == 0 || input < 0{
    return -1 , errors.New(": input is negative or zero-valued, try another input")
}
for steps := 0; input>1; steps++{
    if input % 3 == 0{
        if input % 2 == 0{
            input = input % 2
        }
        input = 3 * input + 1
    }
    if input % 2 == 0{
        input = input % 2
    }
}
return steps , nil 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

При такой форме переменная `steps` имеет [ограниченную циклом область видимости](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1) (`local scope`).
Вынесите её инициализацию перед циклом.

```
steps := 0
for input>1 {
   ...
   steps++  
}
```